# GMail API get From: data out of message

Tags: c#, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to get the sender of an email in my inbox using the GMail API. I can not seem to find anything that will let me do this using the Users.messages.

Comment: Your question is very broad. Try tagging your question with which technology you are using (Java, NodeJs, Python...). Include code you have written so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender will be in `message.payload.headers.From`.

Description of `payload.headers` from the [gmail api reference](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource):

> List of headers on this message part. For the top-level message part, representing the entire message payload, it will contain the standard RFC 2822 email headers such as To, From, and Subject.

Comment: SO do you have to manually parse out the information like this:    
   Message messages = GetMessage(service, userId, messsages[0].Id);
   var type =  messages.Payload.Headers;

            Console.Write(type[8].Name + ": ");
            Console.WriteLine(type[8].Value);'

Comment: Try: `Console.WriteLine(messages.payload.headers.From);`. You can also [try it online](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#net) and see the result.